# can I mount subdir of volume in docker run command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to avoid slow `osxfs` when using docker. So I'm running docker-sync volume container.

I want to mount only subdir of this volume to another container.

[image]

Current example errors out:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create docker-sync/www/marcopolo.front: "docker-sync/www/marcopolo.front" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: Subdirs are perfectly valid. Just make sure that folder exists. The error points to strange characters anyway. And I far as I can see you are using valid chars: letters, period and hyphen. How are you running this command? Maybe there's a charset issue with your alias? Try running the same line from outside that "alias" block you shared.

Comment: @mayid "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" for subdirs I need `/` which is not allowed.

Comment: It is, because I was talking about folder names, and / is a separator. See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/ where it says "Mount a host directory as a data volume"; they explain that and they use subdirs. That's natural, because you may want to place your volume anywhere in your pc.

Comment: Is `docker-sync` the name of a folder in the current directory, or the name of a volume in `docker volume ls`?

Comment: @BMitch it's a volume. I thought it was clear from `So I'm running docker-sync volume container`

Comment: "volume container" implies a data container that you use `--volumes-from`, which would be very different. Hence my confusion. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've seen, docker does not currently provide a way to mount only a sub directory from inside of a named volume. You'll have to mount to entire volume and then either pick your specific files, or you can mount to volume in a separate location and include a symbolic link to your specific subdirectory as part of the image.