# Can I specify a subdirectory for a defined docker volume in compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hello I have a nfs docker volume, and want to mount a file out of one of its subdirectories. Is it possible to do that? My compose file leads to an error currently. Is there a working syntax or do I need a separate volume for each file?

```
version: "3"
    services:
      test:
        image: nginx
        volumes:
          - volume1/subpath/file1:/file1:ro
    ...
    volumes:
     volume1:
      external: true
```

Leads to:

```
->service test: undefined volume "volume1/subpath/file1"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41729237/596285

Comment: @BMitch Yes, doen't seem to be possible, can you mark this as duplicate pls?

Comment: Done. I usually avoid casting the vote since my votes are binding and since I'm the one posting the answer in the dup question. Hope that helped.